# Dynamic attribute-based finders with Active Record RoR, Model.find_by_ does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, dynamic-finders

I am a newby with RoR,

Environment : Rails 3.09 and ruby 1.9.2p290 installed on leopard

I am following carefully the tutorial of Michael hartl (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/). 
At the chapter 7, with the console we should test this code :

```
$ rails console --sandbox
>> User.create!(:nom => "Michael Hartl", :email => "mhartl@example.com",
?>              :password => "foobar", :password_confirmation => "foobar")
>> user = User.find_by_email("mhartl@example.com")
>> user.has_password?("foobar")
=> true
```

My problem is with the use of the attribute based finders , find_by_(the name of the attribute). In my example find_by_email.

Actually, rails doesn't seem to accept find_by_ as a method. Still with the example above, at the line user.has_password?("foobar") rails returns the error : 
NoMethodError: undefined method. The method has_password? is well defined in my model.

I have checked the doc of the api of rails 3.0.9, and if I use this way :

```
>> user = User.where(:email => "mhartl@example.com")
```

then it works....

So I am wondering why I can't use the method find_by_ ? Other find methods work ex: find.first, find.last, etc..
Thank you to help me
fabien

Comment: How does it not work? Does `find_by_email` return `nil`? Please explain better.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the finder works within the model file but not within the console (development environment). 
bizarre 
fabien